# Insert img source in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

Need replace Read More... and Read Less... with images, buttons.

```
$("a", $(this).parent()).text($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Read More...' : 'Read Less...');
```

I tried

```
$("a", $(this).parent()).text($(this).is(':visible') ? '<img src=images/testeon.jpg>' : '<img src=images/testeoff.jpg>');
```

But it shows the src url

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try;

```
$("a", $(this).parent()).html($(this).is(':visible') ? '<img src="images/testeon.jpg">' : '<img src="images/testeoff.jpg">');
```

Comment: String attributes without quotes are invalid HTML.

Comment: Why not change it so you only use the ternary operator on the image path rather than the full `img` element?

Comment: You're welcomw @Ricardo :)

Answer (score 0):

You could set a container around of what you want to replace, then just replace its content with [jQuery's .html() function](http://api.jquery.com/html/#html2)

Here is [an example](http://jsfiddle.net/axX72/)

**HTML:**

```
<a id="myLink" href="javascript:insertImage();">read more..</a>
```

**JS:**

```
function insertImage()
{
    $("#myLink").html("<img src='http://3.bp.blogspot.com/--Fh64MyRDt0/T3XxC6ZVirI/AAAAAAAAJPo/WqHgsEZ7M8Q/s1600/image.php.jpg' />");
}
```

This will replace the content of the link ("read more..") with the given image tag.